# Confused by Java8 Collectors.toMap

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have a collection that looks like below, and I want to filter out the everything except the dates that aren't the end of the months.

```
2010-01-01=2100.00, 
2010-01-31=2108.74, 
2010-02-01=2208.74, 
2010-02-28=2217.92, 
2010-03-01=2317.92, 
2010-03-31=2327.57, 
2010-04-01=2427.57, 
2010-04-30=2437.67, 
2010-05-01=2537.67, 
2010-05-31=2548.22, 
2010-06-01=2648.22, 
2010-06-30=2659.24, 
2010-07-01=2759.24, 
2010-07-31=2770.72, 
2010-08-01=2870.72, 
2010-08-31=2882.66, 
2010-09-01=2982.66, 
2010-09-30=2995.07, 
2010-10-01=3095.07, 
2010-10-31=3107.94, 
2010-11-01=3207.94, 
2010-11-30=3221.29
```

I have the following filter criteria. `frequency.getEnd` returns a `LocalDate` matching the end of the month for the given `LocalDate`.

```
.filter(p -> frequency.getEnd(p.getKey()) == p.getKey())
```

So now I think I have to converted this filtered stream back to a map. And I think I use a collector to do that. Thus I add:

```
.collect(Collectors.toMap(/* HUH? */));
```

But I don't know what to do with `Collectors.toMap`. Reading examples leaves me confused. Here's my current code which obviously doesn't work.

```
TreeMap<LocalDate, BigDecimal> values = values.entrySet()
                                              .stream()
                                              .filter(p -> frequency.getEnd(p.getKey()) == p.getKey())
                                              .collect(Collectors.toMap(/* HUH? */));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to the previous answers note that if you don't need to keep the original map, you can perform such filtering in-place without using the Stream API:

```
values.keySet().removeIf(k -> !frequency.getEnd(k).equals(k));
```

Answer (score 25):

Consider your problem like this: you have a Stream of entry of a map, that is to say a `Stream<Map.Entry<LocalDate, BigDecimal>>`, and you want to collect it into a `TreeMap<LocalDate, BigDecimal>`.

So, you are right, you should use `Collectors.toMap`. Now, as you can see in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html), there are actually 3 `Collectors.toMap`, depending on the arguments:

- [`toMap(keyMapper, valueMapper)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-). `keyMapper` is a function whose input is the stream current element and whose output is the key of the final Map. Thus, it maps the Stream element to a key (hence the name). `valueMapper` is a function whose input is the stream current element and whose output is the value of the final Map.
- [`toMap(keyMapper, valueMapper, mergeFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-). The first two parameters are the same as before. The third, `mergeFunction`, is a function that is called in case of duplicates key elements in the final Map; therefore, its input are 2 values (i.e. the two values for which `keyMapper` returned the same key) and merges those two values into a single one.
- [`toMap(keyMapper, valueMapper, mergeFunction, mapSupplier)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-). The first three arguments are the same as before. The fourth is a supplier of a Map: as it's currently implemented in the JDK, the two preceding `toMap` return a `HashMap` instance. But if you want a specific Map instance, this supplier will return that instance.

In our specific case, we need to use the third `toMap`, because we want the result Map to explicitly be a `TreeMap`. Let's see what input we should give it:

- `keyMapper`: so this should return the key of the final Map. Here, we are dealing with a `Stream<Map.Entry<LocalDate, BigDecimal>>` so each Stream element is of type `Map.Entry<LocalDate, BigDecimal>`. This function then takes a `Map.Entry<LocalDate, BigDecimal> e` as input. Its output should be the key of the final Map, in this case, the output should be `e.getKey()`, i.e. the `LocalDate` that the entry is holding. This can be written as a lambda expression: `e -> e.getKey()`. This could also be written as a method-reference `Map.Entry::getKey` but let's stick with lambdas here, because it might be easier to understand.
- `valueMapper`: this is the same as above, but, in this case, this function needs to return `e.getValue()`, i.e. the `BigDecimal` that the entry is holding. So this is `e -> e.getValue()`.
- `mergeFunction`: this is a tricky one. We know that there are no duplicate key elements (i.e. no duplicate `LocalDate`) in the final Map, by construction. What do we write here? A simple solution is to throw an exception: this should not happen and if it does, there's a big problem somewhere. So whatever the two input arguments, we'll throw an exception. This can be written as `(v1, v2) -> { throw new SomeException(); }`. Note that it needs to be enclosed in brackets. In this case, and to be consistent with what the JDK currently does, I've chosen `SomeException` to be [`IllegalStateException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html).
- `mapSupplier`: as said before, we want to supply a `TreeMap`. A supplier takes no argument and returns a new instance. So this can be written as `() -> new TreeMap<>()` here. Again, we could use a method-reference and write `TreeMap::new`.

Final code, where I've just written the collecting part of the Stream (note that in this code, you could also use the corresponding method-references, as said above, I added them here in comments):

```
Collectors.toMap(
       e -> e.getKey(),    // Map.Entry::getKey
       e -> e.getValue(),  // Map.Entry::getValue
       (v1, v2) -> { throw new IllegalStateException(); },
       () -> new TreeMap<>())  // TreeMap::new
)
```

Comment: I would, but it is way too long

Comment: @njzk2 Well I tried to be as explicit as I could. OP is confused about collectors in general (and maybe lambdas in general) so I think taking the time to explain is a good thing. I agree that there is a whole lot of talk for 6 lines of code in the end, but I feel it's necessary.

Comment: Thanks for so much detail. I think I would have gotten lost on the mergeFunction (because i'm not merging anything), and the mapSupplier. I ended up with some small mods that i've added to the bottom of my post.

Comment: @Patrick Do not add your final code at the end of your post, this breaks the Q&A format of SO. By accepting this answer, you already said to future reader that you thought this was the best answer. I removed it.

Comment: @Tunaki, yes I'm new to the stream api as well as collectors so I don't have it all internalized. Your verbose description was exactly what I needed since my goal is learn rather than ask for the code and move on. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're iterating `Map.Entry` values, and `toMap()` just needs two methods for extracting the key and the value, it's this simple:

```
Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue)
```

Note that this will *not* return a `TreeMap`. For that, you need:

```
Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey,
                 Entry::getValue,
                 (v1,v2) -> { throw new IllegalStateException("Duplicate key"); },
                 TreeMap::new)
```

Answer (score 1):

The toMap method in its simplest form takes two arguments: one is a function to map the input to the key, and the other a function to map the input to the value. The output of both functions is combined to form an entry in the resulting map.

I think you need to do something like this:

```
Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getKey(), p -> p.getValue())
```

Comment: OP wants a `TreeMap` as output, not the current default `HashMap`.

Comment: I can't see that he specifically wants a TreeMap. He shows an example that is using a TreeMap, which does not make it a requirement.

Comment: upped the comment since it solved my purpose; I realize it didn't OP's.