# Collectors.toMap with Supplier argument

Tags: java, lambda

I cannot understand, nor find a suitable example of the Collectors.toMap method with the Supplied argument; [this one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-).

I fully understand the others, with functions to create the keys, the values, the binary thing to handle duplicates, I just don't understand that last method that has an extra supplier argument.

Comment: The extra supplier lets you determine the implementation of the Map to be returned (for example, you can pass HashMap::new or LinkedHashMap::new).

Comment: As the doc show it for a `Collection` with `Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new)`

Comment: Second answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33724733/confused-by-java8-collectors-tomap) has a well explained example

Comment: Good pointer, @RobinTopper, the code at the bottom of [Tunaki’s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33724979/5772882) is fine (this time I linked directly to the answer; use the share link under the answer to obtain a direct link).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you mentioned lets you to decide both:

- the concrete map implementation (e.g. ***HashMap*** , ***ConcurrentHasMap***, etc.. )
- concrete instance of that implementation (you can pass either newly created instance or some instance that is created far ago on the heap of your app)

In contrast to this method, in other 2 overloaded versions the implementation of map will be chosen by library and a new instance of it will be created.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you. One last thing though. What does it mean that, without that supplier argument, the implementation will be chosen "by library" ?

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example:

```
Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3).stream()
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> i, i -> i, (i, j) -> i, HashMap::new));
```

In this example `Supplier<M> mapSupplier` is `HashMap::new`, a factory capable of creating an empty `Map`.