# How to search element in a List?

Tags: java, list, search, arraylist, collections

I have two lists for eg :

List 1 : has only one element

```
List<String> ids=new ArrayList<String>();
```

List 2 : has 1000 objects

```
List<ABC> abc=  new ArrayList<ABC>();

a.matIDS
```

Note:  matIDS is String collection (for eg : abc,def,ghi)

```
for(ABC a : abc){
    for(String id : a.matIDs()){
        if(ids.contains(id)){
            LOG.info("ID found:::");
        }else{
            LOG.info("ID NOT found:::");
        }
    }
}
```

question:

In list 1 there is only 1 element where as in list 2  there are  1000.
Do i need to check all those 1000 to find the 1 element?

Is there any better way?

Comment: maybe you should `break` when you find a match

Comment: In this current situation, looking for only one element in a one off scenario, O(n) is the best you can hope for.  You can speed it up by multithreading or doing something ahead of time _(creating a lookup table of some kind while building the lists)_, but for a single use case it will still be O(n).  If you use it multiple times then there are more efficient ways

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'better way'? Are you asking for a more elegant way to do the search or are you specifically after performance improvements? If it's performance improvements then the answer is probably: don't bother if it's a uncommon search on only 1000s of objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can optimize your existing code to exit the loops when match found.

```
booean isFound=false;
for(ABC a : abc){
    for(String id : a.matIDs()){
        if(ids.contains(id)){
            isFound=true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(isFound)
        break;
}
if(isFound)
    LOG.info("ID found:::");
else
    LOG.info("ID NOT found:::");
```

You may also use streams,

```
boolean isFound=abc.stream().flatMap(e-> e.matIDS.stream()).anyMatch(ids::contains);
if(isFound)
    LOG.info("ID found:::");
else
    LOG.info("ID NOT found:::");
```

To find which elements matched, you can use `filter` and collect in a `Set`

```
  Set<String>  matchedElements=abc.stream()
                .flatMap(e-> e.matIDS.stream())
                .filter(ids::contains)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Will this cover all the scenarios and not only for single elemet?

Comment: It will cover the scenarios you mentioned. Let me know if there are any other scenarios.

Comment: I mean is this scenario only to check 1 element or is it for any number of elements like 1 or 2 or 3 ...n etc? Also in second approcah can i know how to print found element on console?

Comment: It will check for any number of elements. Suppose you have 3 elements a,b,c in list 1 i.e ids , it code will return true if any one the of 3 elements is present in list 2. Hope it helped you.

Comment: Also in second approach can i know how to print found element on console?

Comment: @User2413 I have updated the answer to get matched elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to rapidly lookup a value (or values) in one list against another collection, then perhaps the fastest data structure for this would be to search against a set:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(abc);
```

Then, you may iterate the first list and lookup each entry in constant time in the other collection:

```
for (String id : ids) {
    if (set.contains(id)) {
        LOG.info("ID found:::");
    }
    else {
        LOG.info("ID NOT found:::");
    }
}
```

This is an improvement over your current brute force approach, which was `O(n*m)`, where `n` and `m` are the sizes of the `ids` and `abc` lists.  Now, the running time is just `O(m)`, the size of the `ids` list.

Comment: What is used by default, a HashMap?

Comment: @phflack Good question, that would be my guess.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33724733/confused-by-java8-collectors-tomap) is a SO question which discusses how to generate a `TreeMap`, and it is not the default behavior.

Comment: Looking at `Collectors.toMap()`, looks like it probably uses a HashMap, calling `return toMap(keyMapper, valueMapper, throwingMerger(), HashMap::new);`

Comment: @racraman I store a `null` value, so I would expect performance wise my solution is about the same as using `HashSet`.

Comment: toMap fails on null values https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8148463

Comment: Yes performance wise it would be the same, which leaves the issue which is the most appropriate.  A map is not the most appropriate structure to store single values.  A minor detail (one reason why I deleted the comment, as well as question being a bit unclear)

Answer (score 0):

If by 'better' you mean clearer then perhaps you might consider using streams:

```
abc.stream().flatMap(ABC::matIDs).anyMatch(ids::contains);
```

Whether you consider this 'better' depends on what you are after.

If you are regularly checking whether a particular ID is in the list then you could collect the IDs in a set:

```
Set<String> abcIDs = abc.stream().flatMap(ABC::matIDs).collect(toSet());
```

Then checking if a particular string is in the set is trivial without having to go back to the original list.